# Convergence of a stochastic integral to a normal random variable

Tags: stochastic-integrals, ergodic-theory, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $X_t$ be the [Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein%E2%80%93Uhlenbeck_process) defined by:
$$
X_t = X_0 \, e^{-t} + \int_0^t e^{-(t-s)} dW_s.
$$
Is it possible to show using elementary tools,
in particular without using the central limit theorem for martingales or Markov chains,
that
$$
I_t :=\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}} \int_0^t X_s \, dW_s
$$
converges in distribution to $\mathcal N(0, 1/2)$ as $t \to \infty$?

Comment: Fourth moment theorem?

Comment: @zhoraster Could you elaborate?

Comment: @zhoraster fourth moment theorem is definitely more advanced than the tools OP asked for.

Comment: @user658409, I agree. This is why I didn't write an answer :)